# Can a blockchain be implemented without bitcoin?

Tags: cryptography, distributed, dht, blockchain

Can a blockchain data structure be implemented without the need of a currency?

My idea is to store cryptographic public keys in a distributed and incorruptible data structure. The need is to get the cryptographic public key associated with an identifier and to be sure that the key is really associated with this identifier. Though there is no guarantee without a certification authority or [WoT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust) the idea is to be sure that the key obtained was the first published in the data structure with the identifier and was not overwritten by a malicious node.

So if we have an identifier I can get a cryptographic public key and be sure that it was the first key published with this identifier.

I first though of a [DHT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table) but a data can be easily overwritten by the node storing the key.

So I thought of a blockchain data structure for its property of being secure against corruption.

Does a DHT can be used for that purpose? And how? Can a blockchain be used for that purpose and without the currency involved? Another data structure?

Answer (score 2):

The Linux Foundation's [Hyperledger Project](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric) implements a blockchain that does not require a currency/incentive. There are others that have emerged recently including JP Morgan's [Juno](https://github.com/buckie/juno) and Intel's [IntelLedger](http://intelledger.github.io).

Answer (score 1):

The block chain is simply a directed graph of records where the links are hashed, so if you have a particular head of that data structure all reachable entries from that head are included in that hash. So you can establish a sequence of time.

The crucial part is that the network needs to reach consensus about the current head of the chain and how to decide what the next entry shall be.

So at any given point you can trust the entire *past* history as long as you can establish that a particular block ought to be the current head.

What the blockchain brings to the table is an incentivized proof-of-X scheme that drives the consensus forward in to the future while making forging even a single new block expensive and forging an entire history prohibitively expensive.

Adding a proof-of-X scheme is fairly easy. But incentivizing people to invest considerable resources into that scheme so that a takeover becomes too expensive to perform is not as easy.

One spontaneous idea (not vetted at all!) would be needing refresh of the identifier-key mapping. If they are not refreshed after some interval of X blocks they expire. That way you have to invest in your proof-of-X scheme to keep your own mappings alive, creating value for yourself while also creating the threat that anyone who could control the network could simply let entries expire by refusing to append any transactions to the chain that would renew the mapping.

I think you might want to take further discussion of such theory to the cryptography or bitcoin stack exchanges.